# polymer and apache server

Tags: apache, polymer, web-component

i'm starting to learn polymer and i have installed the starter kit, i have used polymer serve to run the code, and everything works without problems...

After that i tried to use xampp (apache server in windows) and the only thing i see is the title of the web page, i have edited the references to the imports for example:

From

```
<script src="../../webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
```

To

```
<script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js">/script>
```

that solved some problems, now i see the page and seems to work but firebug reports some 404 codes that i could not solve....

Is it correct tha i modify routes or how should i run the code with apache?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to build your project with

> polymer build

After, you can take your built code from the build/bundled and put it in your apache folder.

Be careful the polymer build lack with error handling. Sometimes, if you have some wrong import in your project, the build command don't work well.

Verify, at the end of the build, that you have the "info:    Build complete!" message in your console.

If not, verify your import in your project.

[More info](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/toolbox/deploy)

Comment: thanks, i did what you suggest me, but when i copy the bundled content  (after cli showed the message: 'build complete!')in a new folder in htdocs and open the project in a web browser, it searches resources in localhost instead of localhost/my-app/ and the console shows me this: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js ..... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe polymer buillded app need to be in the root directory of your http server?

Just put your app on the htdocs folder. And if you have other project, just create a folder for them